# angular.js ng-repeat does not seem to be working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular.js version 1.7.2
I have the following code

html

```
<div class="container" ng-app="booksApp"  ng-controller="booksController">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>My Book Catalogue</h1>
         <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Year</th><th>Language</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="book in books">
                     <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
                     <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
                     <td>{{ book.year }}</td>
                     <td>{{ book.language }}</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 


    </div>
</div>
```

In my app.js, I have the following:

```
books = [{'title': 'Finnegans Wake', 'author': 'Janes Joyce', 'language': 'English', 'Year': '1941'},
         {'title': 'Don Quixote', 'author': 'Miguel De Cervantes', 'language': 'Spanish', 'Year': '1615'}
];
angular.module('booksControllers',[]).
            controller('booksController', function($scope){
   $scope.books = books;  
}
})
var booksApp = angular.module('booksApp',[
            'booksControllers',
            'ui.filters'
        ]);
```

The books array has 2 objects. `ng-repeat` is iterated twice, however the value is blank.
`{{book.title }}` and other books elements have blank value.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have a typo, please remove the extra `}` below `$scope.books = books;` line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually using writing the code not insdie a html file, but a `.twig` file.
I found that I can prevent twig from proessing a block by using

```
{% verbatim %}
{% endverbatim %}
```

I added this and now angular.js works as expected. I am sorry I did not mention the problem accurately.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting this, I could get the code working when I moved the array down into the controller:

```
var booksApp = angular.module('booksApp',[
            'booksControllers',
            'ui.filters'
        ]);

 angular.module('booksControllers',[]).
            booksApp.controller('booksController', function($scope){
 $scope.books = [{'title': 'Finnegans Wake', 'author': 'Janes Joyce', 'language': 'English', 'Year': '1941'}, {'title': 'Don Quixote', 'author': 'Miguel De Cervantes', 'language': 'Spanish', 'Year': '1615'} ];
}
})
```

See if that works for you ?

Comment: Give the above edit a go (sorry, I'd comment instead if I could)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  `<html ng-app="myapp">` in your html file  if your app.js is like this. Refer [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/QU4r05n9rQprwyL9Ltxh?p=info)

```
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

        books = [{'title': 'Finnegans Wake', 'author': 'Janes Joyce', 'language': 'English', 'Year': '1941'},
                 {'title': 'Don Quixote', 'author': 'Miguel De Cervantes', 'language': 'Spanish', 'Year': '1615'}
        ];
        app.controller('BaseController', function($scope) {
          $scope.content = 'Hello World';
           $scope.books = books;  
        });


        var booksApp = angular.module('booksApp',[
                    'BaseController',
                    'ui.filters'
                ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a two small issue in your code, the first one you have an extra } and the second one you need to declare your Angular Module name on the top of the controller.

```
    books = [{
  'title': 'Finnegans Wake',
  'author': 'Janes Joyce',
  'language': 'English',
  'Year': '1941'
}, {
  'title': 'Don Quixote',
  'author': 'Miguel De Cervantes',
  'language': 'Spanish',
  'Year': '1615'
}];

var booksApp = angular.module('booksApp', ['booksControllers']);

angular.module('booksControllers', []).
controller('booksController', function($scope) {
  $scope.books = books;
})
```

I have also run it on Plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/XliyEV1leyugSl9gXpnk?p=preview